# Skroll на Jquery к нужному эллементу

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, веб-программирование, frontend

Добрый день)

На сайте, имеется большой список всяких штук. Для удобства пользования подключил плагин который подсвечивает нужные слова которые пользователь вводит в input. 
Подсчечивает он их путем заковывания в тег `<mark>`.
Пытаюсь сделать скроллинг вверх вниз по найденым словам. Т.е. на форме есть еше кнопки вверх / вниз при нажатии на которые экран скроллится вверх и вниз к след. тегу . Пытался вот так сделать:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
        var next;
        $("#downkfm").click(function (){

        if ( next === undefined ) {
        next = $('mark').next();
        } else {
        next = next.next();   
        }

        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: ($('mark').offset().top)
        },500); 

            });
        });
```

И возникло две проблемы:

1 Скролл какой-то косой. Т.е. он прокручивает до нужного тега, но опускается немного ниже его.

2 Не переходит при повторном нажатии к следующему тегу

Подскажите плис что я делаю не так

Comment: Ты в курсе, что делает метод `next`?

Comment: нет, тогда бы не спрашивал

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/next/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scrollTop: ($('mark').offset().top)
```

Вы наверно хотели написать:

```
scrollTop: (next.offset().top)
```

По идее скролл идет до позиции элемента.
Если нужно немного сместить вниз, то можно сделать на подобии:

```
scrollTop: (next.offset().top - 200) 
# 200 пикселей для примера
```

Comment: я наверное идиот, но я попытался вот так:
scrollTop: ($('mark')next().offset().top - 200) 
и понял, что это не правильно.
на странице есть множество слов в теге <mark>. И кнопка. При каждом нажатии на кнопку страница делает скролл к следующему тегу <mark> 

буду рад, если подскажите

Comment: $('mark') вернет массив элементов. нужно поменять _next = $('mark').next();_ на _next = $('mark').first();_. А далее как я написал: _scrollTop: ($('mark').offset().top)_ поменять на _scrollTop: (next.offset().top - 200)_ . Свою переменную next не спутай с методом next() у jQuery. Советую переименовать.

Comment: хмм) поправил, но все рано не прокручивает далее 1 эллемента
$(document).ready(function (){
        var next;
        $("#downkfm").click(function (){

        if ( next === undefined ) {
        next = $('mark').first();
        } else {
        next = next.next();   
        }

        $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: (next.offset().top - 200)
        },500); 

            });
        });

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/73b60mf3/ - лови

Comment: спасибо конечно) но я уже не пойму  что я делаю не так) скопировал листинг, вставил иии ошибка :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
открыл нужную строчку:
  scrollTop: (next.offset().top

Comment: спасибо конечно) но я уже не пойму  что я делаю не так) скопировал листинг, вставил иии ошибка :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
открыл нужную строчку:
  scrollTop: (next.offset().top